# how to validate textbox for NRIC

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am doing a project in c# and window form, and now in testing mode, but i meet a problem

1. I have a text box basically for people to key in their nric, but i don't know how to write the code to validate nric in the textbox
2. Another thing which I never say is I have a student card number, how to validate a length in the text box??

anyone know??? NRIC is like eg S1234567H...so bascially is the front must a be a S character and the middle is a 7 Numerical digit and the last one is any alpabet

thanks in advance

the only thing I know is to put the code inside here:

```
 private void nricTextbox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
 {
 }
```

Comment: I have to google for what is NRCS, is it National Registration Identity Card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have created a simple Windows Forms Application put on form the TextBox component
with name textBox1 and Button control with name ValidateButton in the button click event handler I've written this code

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ValidateSimple
{
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ValidateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strRegex = @"^(S\d{7}[a-zA-Z])$";

        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);

        string strTargetString = textBox1.Text;
        if (myRegex.IsMatch(strTargetString))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"The NRIC is correct!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(@"The NRIC is incorrect!");

        }

    }
  }
}
```

run application and put in the textBox your NRIC and press button
if input correct will show appropriate message, else incorrect NRIC message

also you can use the MaskedTextBox control instead look at the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kkx4h3az.aspx)

and in the property Mask put this S0000000L
S - is your start letter
0 -means any digit 
L - means letter required a-z and A-Z
if you will use the MaskedTextBox control, user cannot enter incorrect value

for mode info look at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx)

Comment: I would recommand use in this case MaskedTextBox controll look at the edited answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to validate input text from textbox. [Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

for example you need to allow to enter in textbox only 10 numbers
look at the code

```
            string strRegex = @"^(\d{10})$";
        Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
        string strTargetString = textBox.Text;

        if(myRegex.IsMatch(strTargetString))
        {
            //all is ok
        }
        else
        {
            //incorrect input
        }
```

if you want simple check input text length use this code

```
if(textBox.Text.Length > 10)
{
    //incorrect length
}
```

insteed  10 put your value

Comment: @serghei is there any simple way to validate the length

Comment: yes simple use if(textBox.Text.Length > 10){// length incorrect}

Comment: @serghei  then do you know how to validate a identify card number ?

Comment: @Serghei...in my question i have show u how a card number look like...then can show me how should i validate a identify cardnumber

Answer (score 0):

use this regex to validate input

```
string strRegex = @"^(S\d{7}[a-zA-Z])$";
```

Comment: show me a more clear code...like how should i  declare to validate this...cause...i don't know what to do with this line of code

Comment: can explain what are the sytnax... @"^(S\d{7}[a-zA-Z])$"

Comment: ..sorry to disturb u...it will be nice if you can show more clearly ....thanks alot